# how to run raw sql with functions in postgres using Query Builder?

Tags: postgresql, laravel, geocoding, postgis

Given a Postgres database with some extensions such as address_standardizer, how to run the below statement with Query Builder:

```
SELECT pprint_addy(normalize_address('202 East Fremont Street, Las Vegas, Nevada 89101'));

Which yields:
 202 E Fremont St, Las Vegas, NV 89101
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run raw select statements with the `DB::select()` method:

```
$data = DB::select('SELECT pprint_addy(normalize_address(?)) as address', ['202 East Fremont Street, Las Vegas, Nevada 89101']);

print_r($data);
```

Comment: I tried this but it does not work. using pg_query_param() works!